# If $u(x,y)$ is not a harmonic function, can a harmonic conjugate $v(x,y)$ be found?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, analyticity, cauchy-riemann-equations

If $u(x,y)$ is **not** a harmonic function, i.e. does **not** satisfy Laplace equation
$$\Delta u(x,y) = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}=0$$
(and perhaps is **not** continously differentiable up to degree 2), can a harmonic conjugate $v(x,y)$ be found so that
$$f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$$
is analytic and therefore $v(x,y)$ is a harmonic conjugate?

Or **must $u(x,y)$ be harmonic for the existence of a harmonic conjugate $v(x,y)$**?

Comment: An analytic function has to be infinite-order differentiable.

Comment: @HoldingArthur Yes, but a **harmonic function** is a twice continuously differentiable function that satisfies Laplace's equation.

Comment: This is impossible. The real part of any analytic function is always harmonic.

Comment: @GReyes Okay, seems reasonable. Do you have any sources or perhaps an explanation?

Comment: If $f=u+iv$ is analytic, you know that the Cauchy-Riemann conditions are satisfied, $\partial u/\partial x=\partial v/\partial y$ and $\partial u/\partial y=-\partial v/\partial x$ and you also know that both $u$ and $v$ are smooth ($C^\infty$) in the given domain. Taking the $x$-derivative of the first, the $y$-derivative of the second and adding them up, it follows that $u$ is harmonic. You prove that $v$ is harmonic in the same way.

Comment: @GReyes So, since a harmonic conjugate to $u(x,y)$ is the function $v(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic, then $u(x,y)$ must be harmonic (because otherwise $f(x,y)$ can not be analytic)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question; this is my conclusion after reading and investigating.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate) a **harmonic conjugate** can be defined as follows:

> A real-valued function $u(x,y)$ defined on a connected open set
>   $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^2$ is said to have a conjugate (function)
>   $v(x,y)$ if and only if they are respectively the real and imaginary
>   parts of a holomorphic function $f(z)$ of the complex variable
>   $z:=x+iy \in \Omega$
>
> That is, $v$ is conjugate to $u$ if $f(z):=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is
>   holomorphic on $\Omega$.

A **holomorphic function** is defined by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function) as:

> A complex-valued function of one or more complex variables that is, at
>   every point of its domain, complex differentiable in a neighborhood of
>   the point.

It also says that "all holomorphic functions are complex analytic functions, and vice versa, is a major theorem in complex analysis".

So for $v(x,y)$ to be a conjugate to $u(x,y)$ the function $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ must holomorphic or analytic.

According to Theorem 5.2 in this [PDF](https://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/18.04/notes/topic5.pdf) from MIT the following is true:

> $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ is analytic on a region $A$ then both $u$ and
>   $v$ are harmonic functions on $A$.

**So in conclusion**; since a harmonic conjugate is defined as $v(x,y)$ being the imaginary part of a holomorphic function $f(z)$ and a holomorphic function must have harmonic parts $u$ and $v$, then $u(x,y)$ must be harmonic for being able to find a harmonic conjugate.

All this is perhaps obvious since it's all in the definitions, but I wanted to post an answer regardless so it becomes obvious.